x-craft-preview pages being blocked due to access forbidden (403)
I'm working on a website using CraftCMS and got a warning from GSC saying pages were "Blocked due to access forbidden (403)"
That never happened before, so I went to check and noticed that it started a couple of weeks ago

All of the pages have the "?x-craft-preview=" parameter, so I assume it is something from the CMS itself (don't know of any changes made from our side).
Anyone seen anything similar? Suggestions on how to resolve?
Thanks

Craft 4.11 (and 5.3) added a new behavior where all URLs generated by Craft would have a x-craft-preview or x-craft-live-preview query param added, if the current request was a preview request (i.e. had a preview param in the original request URL).
A few people reported that – like in your case – Google et. al. had started picking up URLs with those preview params, presumably by GoogleBot having crawled a preview link/URL. Exacerbating the issue was the fact that these preview URLs could end up in sites' template caches, since Craft would potentially cache any request with a preview param, but without a token. These cached page views could even be eligible for indexing, since at the time, Craft also didn't set the X-Robots-Tag: None header unless there was a token in the URL in addition to a preview param.
Fortunately, Craft 4.12 and Craft 5.4 fixed these problems by

Setting the X-Robots-Tag: None header for all preview requests
Disabling template caches for all preview requests
No longer adding preview query params to generated URLs, if their values are invalid

My advice is to make sure your site is updated to Craft 4.12/5.4 or later, and this shouldn't be something to worry about anymore in most cases.
